# Converting a SecureString to a byte array

Tags: c#, security, memory-management, serialization, securestring

Does it allocates something that hasn't freed? Something that remains in memory? Except result byte array, ofc.

```
private unsafe byte[] ToByteArray(SecureString secureString, Encoding encoding = null)
{
    if (secureString == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(secureString));
    if (encoding == null)
        encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    int maxLength = encoding.GetMaxByteCount(secureString.Length);

    IntPtr bytes = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(maxLength);
    IntPtr str   = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(secureString);

    try
    {
        char* chars = (char*)str.ToPointer();
        byte* bptr  = (byte*)bytes.ToPointer();
        int len     = encoding.GetBytes(chars, secureString.Length, bptr, maxLength);

        byte[] _bytes = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            _bytes[i] = *bptr;
            bptr++;
        }

        return _bytes;
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(bytes);
        Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Relevant reading](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/29019). TL;DR: Nothing is safe when the OS writes your RAM to disk.

Comment: The encoding.GetBytes(char*, int, byte*, int) method allocates a managed char[] array and copies the string into it, and thus it voids all the security which was attempted to be preserved. See the source of the method here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/encoding.cs,60e5984b6a8c4e7a

Answer (score 11):

Although you have done a decent job, you could do this in a better way, without even to use `unsafe`.

First thing to mention, you should always use braces `{}` although they are optional for single lined `if` statements. This will just make your code less error prone which is in such a security context wanted.

Instead of using `if (encoding==null) { encoding = Encoding.UTF8; }` you can use the null coalescing operator `??`.

How I use this usually (integrated in your method)

```
private byte[] ToByteArray(SecureString secureString, Encoding encoding = null)
{
    if (secureString == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(secureString));
    }

    encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;

    IntPtr unmanagedString = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        unmanagedString = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(secureString);

        return encoding.GetBytes(Marshal.PtrToStringUni(unmanagedString));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (unmanagedString != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(unmanagedString);
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the valid comment

> Marshal.PtrToStringUni allocates managed string so until GC clear this we will have unprotected string with sensitive data in memory.

I would like to suggest another aproach which depends on your implementation. The main problem I see is that with your implementation the returned `byte[]` needs to be cleaned up from the caller of the code.

How about having a class which implements `IDisposable` which is wrapping the shown method ?

```
public sealed class SecureStringWrapper : IDisposable  
{
    private readonly Encoding encoding;
    private readonly SecureString secureString;
    private byte[] _bytes = null;

    public SecureStringWrapper(SecureString secureString)
          : this(secureString, Encoding.UTF8)
    {}

    public SecureStringWrapper(SecureString secureString, Encoding encoding)
    {
        if (secureString == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(secureString));
        }

        this.encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8
        this.secureString = secureString;
    }

    public unsafe byte[] ToByteArray()
    {

        int maxLength = encoding.GetMaxByteCount(secureString.Length);

        IntPtr bytes = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr str   = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            bytes = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(maxLength);
            str   = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(secureString);

            char* chars = (char*)str.ToPointer();
            byte* bptr  = (byte*)bytes.ToPointer();
            int len     = encoding.GetBytes(chars, secureString.Length, bptr, maxLength);

            _bytes = new byte[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            {
                _bytes[i] = *bptr;
                bptr++;
            }

            return _bytes;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (bytes != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(bytes);
            }
            if (str != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(str);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            Destroy();
            _disposed = true;
        }
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Destroy()
    {
        if (_bytes == null) { return; }

        for (int i = 0; i < _bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            _bytes[i] = 0;
        }
        _bytes = null;
    }

    ~SecureStringWrapper()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

now the caller could use it like so

```
using (SecureStringWrapper wrapper = new SecureStringWrapper(secureString))
{

    byte[] _bytes = wrapper.ToByteArray();
    // use _bytes like wanted

}
```

A good read about the topic of `SecureString`: http://web.archive.org/web/20090928112609/http://dotnet.org.za/markn/archive/2008/10/04/handling-passwords.aspx

Comment: This is pretty much the "by the book" implementation. It hangs on to the string for the absolute minimum amount of time. +1.

Comment: `Marshal.PtrToStringUni` allocates managed string so until GC clear this we will have unprotected string with sensitive data in memory. I might be wrong, but it seems to be less secure.

Comment: Since C# internally stores strings as UTF-16, wouldn't it be better to use that instead of UTF-8?

Comment: Shouldn't you clear the `bptr` too? Or `FreeHGlobal` will clear its content?

Comment: Regarding your second solution: If someone calls `wrapper.ToByteArray()` multiple times, aren't all `_bytes` instances except the last one left for GC? Only the last instance will be cleaned up by Dispose. I added this first line to `ToByteArray` to check this:
`if (this.bytes != null) return this.bytes;`
correct me if I'm wrong about this.

Comment: seems that the first code sample should use ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode instead of ZeroFreeBSTR

Comment: @tomasz_kajetan_stanczak > I was encountering a ViolationAccessException with ZeroFreeBSTR, I tried the change you said and it seems to work fine now, thanks.

Answer (score -3):

I guess the `Finally`-block is not executed if the return statement makes it leave before then. Due to this the free is not called.

Comment: The finally block is always reached wether there is an exception thrown or a return statement before.

Comment: Not in case of an an asynchronous exception happening on the thread (e.g. OutOfMemoryException, StackOverflowException).

Comment: Exceptions like OutOfMemory are sometimes referred to as ["fatal" exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) and there's nothing you can do about them. The only thing really worth doing is logging that they happened.